# IE not calculating correctly using getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I thought I had my Angular app's D3 axis working in Internet Explorer but after developing for a few weeks in Chrome I realized today that it is now broken in IE.

I have 3 parts to my X axis. One is the date labels, next is the hour labels, and then "bars" to represent each hour.

It looks like this in Chrome:
[image]

In IE 11 the width calculation is failing. Here's the code for the alternating bars:

```
hoursBarUpperG
  .selectAll('.tick')
  .sort(function(a: any, b: any) {
    return ascending(a, b);
  })
  .each(function(this: any, _d: any, i: any) {
    if (this.nextSibling) {
      select(this)
        .append('rect')
        .attr(
          'width',
          this.nextSibling.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x - this.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x
        )
        .attr('height', 6)
        .attr('class', i % 2 ? 'lightGrayBar' : 'darkGrayBar');
    }
  });
```

The problem is that the rect is getting appended with the attribute 'width' coming out as 'Nan'. 
In Chrome the getBoundingClientRect() returns a DOMRect. In IE I get a ClientRect which doesn't have a 'x' field.

Is there a better alternative than using getBoundingClientRect() so that I can properly set the width of these bars?

Answer (score 3):

Update: I discovered that changing the code to use 'left' instead of 'x' seems to resolve the issue in IE.

```
this.nextSibling.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().left - this.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().left
```

I would still love to hear if anyone has a better idea for doing this calculation though!